# Filtering using php if statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

Quick question I have a fully functional database website apart from the filter aspect. I had a javascript filter but it would not work with the database properly as it filtered via li class and making it li class=' . name . ' did not work.

Anyway I have attempted to use this method to get around the filter problem.

However I do not know where to run the query that wont create an error hence why it is commented out. Can anyone help or even suggest a better method of going about this?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ddcompanies");

/*
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $cname = $row["company"]; //runs through the company column and populates the array varcompany with those names
    $csect = $row["sector"]; //runs through the website column and populates the array varwebsite with those names
    $cslog = $row["slogan"]; //runs through the story column and populates the array varstory with the text
*/

echo "<ul id='portfolio'>";

if($_GET['link']=='design'){

    echo "design";// TEST
    $result .= "AND sector = 'design'";

echo "<li>
    <a href='single.php?link=" . $cname . "'><img src='images/companies/" . $cname . ".png' alt='' height='115' width='200' />$cname</a>
    <div id='sector'>$csect</div>
    <div id='details'>$cslog</div>
</li>";

}else{
    echo "no way";// TEST
};
```

Hope you can help or even tell me a better way to do it please.

Thanks in advance!

****EDIT*****

On my index page i have a grid or gallery of links (which have an image and some info all pulled from a database).

Each database entry has a field called sector.

I want to be able to only show (filter) the grid items that fall under e.g. Digital (sector name) or Non-Digital (sector name).

So the filter will be using the sector field value in each database entry.

At the moment my links on the index page for filtering are like the following e.g. Design or Development

I hope this is clear enough.

*EDIT****

```
//QUERY IN EACH

$query = "SELECT * FROM ddcompanies ";
if($_GET['link']=='design') {
    $query .= "WHERE sector = 'design'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
}elseif($_GET['link']=='development') {  
    $query .= "WHERE sector = 'development'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
};

//OR

$query = "SELECT * FROM ddcompanies ";
if($_GET['link']=='design') {
    $query .= "WHERE sector = 'design'";
}elseif($_GET['link']=='development') {  
    $query .= "WHERE sector = 'development'";
};
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I'm confused, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry it must have been badly explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you're trying to append to your query string based on the URL parameter (link) in the case you posted above.  The way you're doing it won't work though as $result is a resource, not a string so you can't just append another string to the resource.

You'd have to create a string variable for your query, then plug that into your mysql_query() function.

You'd also have to move the logic up above the string declaration that checks how to revise the query.

Finally, you need a WHERE clause put in there as just using *AND sector = 'design'* would break the query as it is now.

**EDIT (added some pseudo-code):**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ddcompanies ";
if(isset($_GET['link']))    
        $query .= "WHERE sector = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['link'])."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Thanks so much that is a great help mate and exactly what I was after. If I was going to add more e.g. would i run a query every time or just once at the end? edit my original up above. ^^^

Comment: depends on a few things.  Namely if the field on which your searching from the database is the same or different.  You just need to build your query accordingly.  You can use IN() if it's the same field or you can use OR and add each value separately.  If it's a different field, you'll need to use AND and append the fieldname / value combination.  The important thing is that you build the query first before you pump it into the mysql_query() function.

Comment: Ah that's what I didn't understand about the positioning of the query and while. Thank you so much. All the sectors will be the same in my database as in the queries. I do not understand what you mean by in() though. Would my second example above with the query at the bottom work or is there anything wrong with that code?

Comment: Ah sorry ok :) Disregard previous comment please

Comment: You are a legend. Tried it and added in formatting and everything and works perfect. Thanks very much mate really appreciate it. Was doing my head in :) Need to learn how to code properly after this :)